# Gif Animation in Gnuplot

Tags: animation, gnuplot, gif

I have a data file separated by two lines. Each section of data is ~50 lines. I'm trying to make a .gif file. I know how to plot them individually or in a group but can't get the .gif to work.

My problem is similar to the one worked out by Glen MacLachlan in his youtube channel, part 5. Instead of 1 point, I have ~50 data points for each data section. He solves the problem by utilizing $index feature, and I tried to do the same but mine doesn't work.

What am I missing? Do I really have to plot the data separately into .png files and group them together to get .gif file?

What I've done:::

I edited the data file. Previously there were two columns x, and y. Now, I have them in 2nd and 3rd column, and the first column is index from 0 to 50. Each block of data has similar index.

bash script to create plot file

```
for ((i=0;i < 50; i++)) do echo "plot 'data.txt' 
u 2:3 w circles index $i"; done >>simulate.plt
```

It just plots ALL the data points

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Why don't you show what you have tried?

The following should work fine:

```
set terminal gif animate delay 100
set output 'foobar.gif'
stats 'datafile' nooutput
set xrange [-0.5:1.5]
set yrange [-0.5:5.5]

do for [i=1:int(STATS_blocks)] {
    plot 'datafile' index (i-1) with circles
}
```

with the file `datafile`:

```
0
1


2
3


4
5
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It gives me an error saying that x-range is invalid. I tried plot 'datafile' u 1:2 as well. When I removed the index (i-1) part, it did produce a file, but it plotted all the data multiple times.

Comment: I updated the answer to give a full, running example. If it still doesn't work for you, please give a link to your data file and a minimal, but runnable example script which shows the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It isn't perfect, but I'm getting .gif file that "animates".

Comment: Sorry, forgot to update my answer. Now, it works as I expected. Thanks again.

Comment: @Christoph I'm trying something similar, could you take a look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430479/gnuplot-from-data-file-for-assignment-in-do-for-loop-for-an-animation

Comment: @Christoph I've got a very large file with 20000 timesteps. Somehow gnuplot detects only 1001 blocks and stops the animation after that without throwing an exception. Do you have an idea what could be the problem?