# Gnuplot from data file for assignment in do for loop for an animation

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Say I have a data file like so:

```
1.3 4.23
1.23 5.667
.
.
.
```

These are the constants for my line. I want to make this into an animated gif but I'm having trouble getting particular data.

So far, I'm doing

```
set terminal gif animate delay 50
set output 'test.gif'
stats 'temp.dat' nooutput
set xrange[-1:1]
set yrange[-1:1]
h(x) = a*x + b
```

and here is where I'm having trouble. I tried these two approaches:

```
do for [i=1:int(STATS_records)]{
   plot h(x) u (a=$1):(b=$2) w l
}
```

and this one:

```
plot 'temp.dat', f(x) = ($1)*x + ($2)
```

Neither is working. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to extract parameters from a file, you must call `stats` in every iteration and select only the i-th row with `every`

```
set terminal gif animate delay 50
set output 'test.gif'

set xrange[-10:10]
set yrange[-10:10]
h(x) = a*x + b

stats 'temp.dat' nooutput
N = int(STATS_records) - 1

do for [i=0:N] {
  stats 'temp.dat' every ::i::i nooutput
  a = STATS_min_x
  b = STATS_min_y
  plot h(x) with lines
}
```

Comment: Excellent! This worked, I just added `set terminal gif animate delay 50` and `set output 'test.gif'` at the top of the script. You know gnuplot very well! Thank you.

Comment: The animation works, but I'm trying to integrating it with the rest of my code. Code is here: https://gist.github.com/fxfactorial/b488cff19104e316eba7 Basically I want to first add red and blue dots and one line and then plot on top of that the animation, but right now I'm getting an incorrect back and forth of an animation and then the initial plot. Do I need to do a replot? Very much appreciate your help. Relevant lines are 36 and 81

Comment: I'm not sure, if I get you right, but if you want to keep the blue and red dots during the whole animation, you must also replot those values anew in every iteration.

Comment: yes, I wanted to have one initial frame with the blue and red dots and one line. Then on top of that I wanted the animation, but now I see what you mean, the dots would need to be redrawn in each iteration.