# Gnuplot 3d time animation from data file

Tags: gnuplot

I realise this is perhaps trivial and if I had more time I'd probably easily deal with it myself, but I'm running out of time and I desperately need to get this animation working as soon as possible.

I have data file of the type

```
0          28.3976  25.1876  12.7771 
0.03125    34.1689  21.457   9.70863 
0.0625     35.7084  17.6016  5.03987 
0.09375    34.3048  13.6718  1.45238 
...
```

where the first column is meant to be treated as time (it is in fact a numerical solution to a certain ODE system). Now. what I need is an animation of a 3d plot of the last three columns tracing a curve as it moves around with time. Is that doable? If so, how? I'm a complete gnuplot beginner and googling around did not help much. I would hugely appreciate any help. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should show you an animated plot:

```
# define fixed axis-ranges
set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [0:20]
set zrange [-1:1]

# filename and n=number of lines of your data 
filedata = 'data.dat'
n = system(sprintf('cat %s | wc -l', filedata))

do for [j=1:n] {
    set title 'time '.j
    splot filedata u 2:3:4 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
          filedata u 2:3:4 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2
}
```

The first line of the splot command plots the trayectory, and the second line plots the point at the current time.

If you want a gif of this output, simply add the following before the for-loop:

```
set term gif animate
set output 'output.gif'
```

This is an example output:
[image: example]

Related:

- [StackOverflow: Gif Animation in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899696/2174266)
- [gnuplot-surprising: creating gif animation](http://gnuplot-surprising.blogspot.cl/2011/09/creating-gif-animation-using-gnuplot.html)
- [gnuplotting: Animation IV – trajectory](http://www.gnuplotting.org/tag/animation/)

Comment: That's amazing, I can't express how thankful I am. Thank you so much! Also, just a tiny typo, it should be " set title 'time '.j " instead of "set title 'time '.i". But other than that, it works perfectly!

Comment: +1. Addition: one could also use `stats filedata using 1 nooutput; n = STATS_records` to extract the number of points.