# is there a way in gnuplot to give a gif a more specific time title other than time.1, time.2 , time.3?

Tags: time, gnuplot, animated-gif, plot3d

From an answer given here [Gnuplot 3d time animation from data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142292/gnuplot-3d-time-animation-from-data-file)
I changed it a bit adding a filedata 2, now the problem is i have a filedata with

```
column1  column2      column3      column4
time       x            y            z
0          54           89            787
0.15       90           676           345
0.70       4593         34            387
3.78       59           37            904
```

and so on with other time positions data (actually in my .dat file I didn't write time x y z ,only the values).
What I'd like to do is to take column 1 values and put its values in place of `.j` in `'time'.j`.
Is there a way to do it?

```
# define fixed axis-ranges
set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [0:20]
set zrange [-1:1]

# filename and n=number of lines of your data 
filedata = 'data.dat'
n = system(sprintf('cat %s | wc -l', filedata))
 
do for [j=1:n] {
    set title 'time '.j
    splot filedata1 u 2:3:4 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
          filedata1 u 2:3:4 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2,\
          filedata2 u 2:3:4 every ::1::j w l lw 2, \
          filedata2 u 2:3:4 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2
}
```

Actually as of now I don't know how to put it to work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do I understand correctly that your `filedata2` actually has just 3 columns `x,y,z`? Do the two files have the same number of rows?

Comment: yes , the other file has time too, but the time is the same one of the file 1 so i can keep it only in filedata 1 and use filedata 2 with only x,y,z  and it works, thank you very much for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize what I've understood from your question:

- you have two files one with 4 columns (time,x,y,z) and the other with 3 columns (x,y,z)
- I further assume that those files have the same number of rows and the rows of the second file correspond also to the time of the first file
- you want to animate the trajectories from both files with a label containing the time from the column 1 of the first file

**Comments:**

- in order to find out the number of rows, you could use `stats` (check `help stats`). With this gnuplot-only and platform-independent, unlike your `n = system(sprintf('cat %s | wc -l', filedata))`
- row index starts at `0`, e.g. `every ::0::j`. But since you have a headerline this line will not be plotted because it is text data.
- there is the plotting style `with labels`. With this you can plot the value from column 1 somewhere as label, here at x,y,z `... u (7):(10):(10) ...`.

**Data:**

`SO74583831_1.dat`

```
t       x     y     z
 0      1.0   2.0   3.0
 0.15   2.0   5.0   4.0
 0.70   5.0   3.0   5.0
 3.78   7.0   7.0   6.0
 5.13   5.0   4.0   7.0
 7.45   3.0   4.0   8.0
10.99   1.0   1.0   9.0
```

`SO74583831_2.dat`

```
x     y     z
4.0   4.0   9.0
7.0   5.0   8.0
6.0   6.0   7.0
3.0   3.0   6.0
2.0   2.0   5.0
5.0   1.0   4.0
9.0   3.0   3.0
```

**Script:**

```
### plot two animated trajectories, 2nd file without time
reset session

FILE1 = "SO74583831_1.dat"
FILE2 = "SO74583831_2.dat"

stats FILE1 u 0 nooutput
N = STATS_records

set xrange[0:10]
set yrange[0:10]
set zrange[0:10]
set key noautotitle
set xyplane at 0

set terminal gif animate delay 60
set output "SO74583831.gif"

do for [j=0:N-1] {
    splot FILE1 u 2:3:4 every ::0::j w l lw 2 lc "red", \
             '' u 2:3:4 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "red" ti "Particle 1", \
             '' u (7):(10):(10):(sprintf("Time: % 6.2f",$1)) every ::j::j with labels left, \
          FILE2 u 1:2:3 every ::0::j w l lw 2 lc "blue", \
             '' u 1:2:3 every ::j::j w p pt 7 ps 2 lc "blue" ti "Particle 2", \
}
set output
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]