# Syntax of animating in gnuplot using 'blocks' in a single file

Tags: animation, gnuplot

I have a data file of two column, ten row ‘blocks’, with two lines of whitespace between each block. Each frame of the animation I want the ten points in the successive block to be plotted, until the end of the data file.

I've searched for how to do this for ages but can't appropriate any of the examples I've found to my case as I don't understand the syntax and can't find an explanation of it anywhere.

How would the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898971/gif-animation-in-gnuplot) or [here](http://gnuplot.10905.n7.nabble.com/how-to-make-animation-td5877.html) be extended to blocks of x rows?

E.g., in the second example, pasted below for easy reference

```
n=10  # n present here the number of blocks in your file
plot  "output.dat" using 1:2 every :::i::i
i=i+1
if i<n reread
```

What do the number of colons in `every :::i::i` mean? Is that three data lines, then two whitespace lines? (Appropriating assuming that doesn't work.)

(If this question seems too obvious, I assure you it is due to my lack of knowledge, not my lack of effort in researching. I would very gladly accept being pointed towards the place in the documentation where this is covered.)

Comment: What does this have to do with C and C++?

Comment: I didn't realize gnuplot could be used independently of C and C++, as I've always been taught to use them together. I'll remove those tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer regarding the syntax of `every`, but a way to achieve this animated plot that is scalable for future users in my position.

A datablock, or block, is x consecutive lines of data, separated by exactly two lines of whitespace.

The plot command option `index` can be used to access each of these blocks.

For example, `plot "datafile.dat" using 1:2 index 1` would plot only the points in the first dataset (block of data).

A loop can be used to animate your data. The `stats` command can be used to find the number of datasets/blocks in your file, to use in the loop.

```
set terminal x11

stats 'bdata.txt' nooutput

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [0:10]

do for [a = 1: int(STATS_blocks - 1)] {
        plot "bdata.txt" using 1:2 index a
        pause 0.1
}
```