# Creating an animation of moving audio levels using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot, and am trying to use it to create an animation of moving audio levels like this GIF:

[Moving audio levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XQ8J.gif)

I understand that I need to use a command like this to write out a series of PNG files that can be used to create a video:

```
set output sprintf('hrir_frame%03.0f.png',ii)
```

And I presume that I should use a .dat file with the audio levels on each line like this:

```
4
9
-3
-5
2
...
```

However, I'm confused as to how to make gnuplot slide from one value to the next as in the GIF above.

Comment: Hello. I think you need to provide more information. Do you have a few input files to put here as examples? There are many ways to approach this, but one would be creating a series on png files and then combining them using a `convert` or something similar, depending on your OS. Also, try to search a bit more on google and SO, because this was answered before (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22898971/gif-animation-in-gnuplot)

Comment: @ViniciusPlacco, that example is different as it transitions from 0-1 to 2-3. For each frame, I want to slide a value off and add another in. So in this instance, it should show 0-1 on the first frame and 1-2 on the next. But I don't know how to structure the dat file or the gnuplot code to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move through your data with the `every` specifier:

```
datafile = "data.dat"
set terminal pngcairo

stats datafile
set yrange [STATS_min_y*1.2:STATS_max_y*1.2]

npoints = 100  # Always show 100 data points.

do for [ii=0:STATS_records-npoints] {
   set output sprintf('hrir_frame%03.0f.png',ii)
   print ii
   plot datafile every ::ii::ii+npoints w lp notitle
}
```

This produces a set of image files which can then be combined into a movie.

Another option might be to use the `gif` terminal with animation:

```
datafile = "data.dat"
set terminal gif size 300,200 animate delay 2
set output "moving.gif"

stats datafile
set yrange [STATS_min_y*1.2:STATS_max_y*1.2]

npoints = 100

do for [i=0:STATS_records-npoints] {
   print i
   plot datafile every ::i::i+npoints w lp notitle
}
```

The important part in both scripts is

```
plot datafile every ::i::i+npoints
```

Please type `help every` for detailed information, the entries `i` and `i+npoints` correspond to the first datapoint and the number of datapoints.

In order to have consistent scalings on each plot, the y-range is adjusted with `set yrange`. The limits come from the `stats` command but could be set manually.

The gif result looks like this (it is quite large and might not meet your speed requirements, maybe this can be optimized):

[image: moving]

The sample data was created with

```
datafile = "data.dat"
set print datafile

do for [i=0:500] {
   print    sin(2.0*pi*1.0*(i/100.0))      \
          + sin(2.0*pi*2.0*((i+25)/100.0)) \
          + sin(2.0*pi*3.0*((i+15)/100.0))
}
```

Comment: thank you, this looks like it's on the right track. Unfortunately though I get this message:`"test", line 5: undefined variable: STATS_min_y` any ideas @maij ?

Comment: Maybe a different gnuplot version? I use 5.0 on Debian Jessie. `STATS_min_y` and `STATS_max_y` are used to have the same range on each plot, you can set them manually. They should be the output of `stats`. You can check whether they exist by typing `show variables` just after the `stats` command. The same applies to `STATS_records`: If it does not exist, set it manually.

Comment: @maji, It looks like they are named `STATS_min` and `STATS_max` for me. Changing to those 2 worked. Thank for your help!